# C# - Move TextBox to ListBox and be able to use Add/Remove Buttons

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox, datasource, move

I have 3 textboxes that have certain values in them. The values are split up depending on what the strings contain using different regex.

These textboxes are in the background and the user will not see them.. However, I *do* want the user to see the listboxes that correspond to each textbox.  ***That is what the code below is:***

```
    private void listFormatHelper()
    {
        // Splits the lines in the rich text boxes
        var listOneLines = placementOneRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');
        var listTwoLines = placementTwoRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');
        var listUserLines = userDefinedRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');

        // Resest the text in the listboxes
        placementOneListBox.ResetText();
        placementTwoListBox.ResetText();
        userDefinedListBox.ResetText();

        // Set the selection mode to multiple and extended.
        placementOneListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
        placementTwoListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
        userDefinedListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;

        // Shutdown the painting of the ListBox as items are added.
        placementOneListBox.BeginUpdate();
        placementTwoListBox.BeginUpdate();
        userDefinedListBox.BeginUpdate();

        // Display the items in the listbox.
        placementOneListBox.DataSource = listOneLines;
        placementTwoListBox.DataSource = listTwoLines;
        userDefinedListBox.DataSource = listUserLines;

        // Allow the ListBox to repaint and display the new items.
        placementOneListBox.EndUpdate();
        placementTwoListBox.EndUpdate();
        userDefinedListBox.EndUpdate();
    }
```

---

***HOWEVER***, my problem with this is that I cannot move each item in the list... What I mean is that I want to be able to have `Move up`, `Move down`,`Move left`, and `Move right` buttons.  The `Move up` and `Move down` buttons will allow the user to move the selected item(s) up or down *(to change the order of the items)* in the specified list.  The `Move left` and `Move right` buttons will allow the user to **move** the item on the current list to the list to the "right" or "left" of the current list.

***VISUAL LAYOUT OF LISTBOXES:***

```
placementOneListBox                userDefinedListBox                placementTwoListBox
|                 |                |                 |               |                 |
|                 |                |                 |               |                 |
|                 |                |                 |               |                 |
|                 |                |                 |               |                 |
|_________________|                |_________________|               |_________________|
```

*and* I get the ***error***:

```
"Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set."
```

---

***Move Up Button CODE:***

```
    private void moveUpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (placementOneListBox.SelectedIndex != 0 && placementOneListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            object item = placementOneListBox.SelectedItem;
            int index = placementOneListBox.SelectedIndex;
            placementOneListBox.Items.RemoveAt(index);
            placementOneListBox.Items.Insert(index - 1, item);
        }
    }
```

---

***Move Right Button CODE:***

```
    private void moveRightButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < placementTwoListBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            userDefinedListBox.Items.Add(placementTwoListBox.Items[i].ToString());
            placementTwoListBox.Items.Remove(placementTwoListBox.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

---

***QUESTIONS:***

- Is there a way to go about this where I can modify the DataSource property?
- Does anyone want to take a crack at this?
- How can I change my listFormatHelper() function to do what I need it to do and allow the buttons to work without the error above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Don't use data binding; convert the data source to a sequence of objects and populate the list(s) by adding the objects in the sequence to the `Items` property.  Then manage the order using the `Items` property, as you are currently trying to do.
2. Modify the data source itself to alter the order.  How you do this depends on which data source you are using.

Comment: How do I convert the data source to a sequence of objects?

Comment: Instead of setting the `DataSource` property, enumerate the list and add each item using `Items.Add()`.

Comment: would that just be changing  `placementOneListBox.DataSource = listOneLines;` to `placementOneListBox.Items.Add(listOneLines);` ?

Comment: No, that would add the whole list object as one item.  You want something like `foreach (var line in listOneLines) placementOneListBox.Items.Add(line);`.

Comment: Nice I just tried that right before you posted. That seems to work so far.. let me continue testing..

Comment: For some reason when the `Move right` button is clicked the entire `placementOneListBox` is copied over to the `userDefinedListBox` **EXCEPT** for the value that I tried to move over... it is deleted from both Lists... error in the `moveRightButton_Click` function?

Comment: Yes.  You are looping over the entire Items collection.  Use the SelectedIndex property (make sure it's not -1 first) and move only the object at that index.

Comment: So would I just change the contents of the `moveRightButton_Click` to this instead: `if (placementOneListBox.SelectedIndex != -1) { for (int i = 0; i < placementOneListBox.Items.Count; i++) { userDefinedListBox.Items.Add(placementOneListBox.Items[i].ToString()); placementOneListBox.Items.Remove(placementOneListBox.SelectedItem); } }` ?

Comment: No, you would not.  Why do you think you need a loop to move *one item?*

Comment: If there are *multiple* items selected?

Comment: I removed the *for loop* and the `.ToString()`..and it now removes the item from the current list and adds the *text* `(Collection)`. Do you know how I could display the actual item text instead of `(Collection`?

Comment: private void placementOneMoveRightButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (placementOneListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                userDefinedListBox.Items.Add(placementOneListBox.Items).ToString();
                placementOneListBox.Items.Remove(placementOneListBox.SelectedItem);
            }
        }

Comment: `userDefinedListBox.Items.Add(placementOneListBox.Items)` adds the whole items collection from the first box to the second box.  That's not what you want, is it?  Then the `.ToString()` call converts the return value of `Add()` to a string and throws the result away.  Try `userDefinedListBox.Items.Add(placementOneListBox.SelectedItem)`.

Comment: Do you know how I could change it so I can select multiple items in the list and move them all at the same time?

Comment: You'd have to loop over the SelectedIndices property and move each item.  But note that removing an item will change the indices of the following items.